# Firebase http.function's server rendered page In conjunction with Create-React-App router

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, create-react-app

Is it possible insert/update html from firebase function, connected to firebase's hosted Create-React-App's route, and prerender html's meta tags for React page?
in my experiment:

Function's index.js:

```
exports.productPage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const html = `<!doctype html>
    <head>
      <title>Function</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h5>FUNCTION</h5>
      <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
  </html>`
  res.status(200).send(html);
  })
```

React routes:

```
<Route path='/product/:_id' component={ProductPage}/>
```

firebase.json:

```
"rewrites": [ {
   "source": "/product/**", "function": "productPage"
 } ]
```

If i go to function's or hosting's url, i get markup, generated from function only and not react component with new title from function.
Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you can go with. What you have to do is depends on what are you trying to achieve.

With your approach you need to somehow implement a function that renders and inserts HTML that returned from the cloud function. Rather then returning a HTML code from the function you can consider returning a JSON result then parsing and inserting the required tags with React. You can use `react-helmet`.

Another approach is if you are using Firebase for your database; you can use **Firebase Javascript SDK** to populate required data on your React Component.

Another approach is that you can use your own implementation of an api and populate data with using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Another approach is that you can use [Express](https://expressjs.com/) with Cloud Functions and you can use a server side render middleware for React.

I'm sure there are lots of approaches that I can't think of right now. I would suggest you to make some more reading about React and Node to find the best approach for yourself.

Comment: The key point in my question is to stay within the Create React App, did you take it into your answer?

Comment: Yes I did. All of the approaches I told you about are compatible with react. create-react-app just helps you to create and build a react app. Fetch API is integrated within react itself.

Comment: thanks for response, 
could you show a small example how I can insert into <div id="root"></div> a returned html from a function

Comment: I don't suggest you to return html and insert it into react as html. I suggest you to return a json or similar data from an api and render that data as html with react.